# What Parameters are required for Save Method in aspx.cs file So that Ajax Can Call This method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, asp.net-ajax

This Script is Written in .aspx file i am tryoing to upload images through ajax in WebForms in Asp.net how can i call the method in .aspx.cs file and send it image as an argument

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();    
        formdata = new FormData();      
        jQuery("#image_to_upload").on("change", function() {
            var file = this.files[0];
            if (formdata) {
                formdata.append("image", file);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "frmGallery.aspx/Save",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (r) {
                        alert(r.d);
                    },
                    error: function (r) {
                        alert(r.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }                       
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Please include the method as part of the question

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncFileUpload control in the Ajax Control Toolkit will fire a client side event.

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
     OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server"
     ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" UploaderStyle="Modern"
     UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF" ThrobberID="myThrobber"
/>
```

http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx